# How to retrieve parent menu item name of current submenu item

Tags: menus, pages, sub-menu, child-pages

I have a menu item Services which has 5 submenus. Now when I click on one of those submenus, like `Flexible Endoscopes` I manage to echo the title of child item or current page title. But I can't find any info on how to output parent menu item name. I found a method called `menu_item_parent` but that just prints number to the screen and not the title. How can I echo both `Services` menu name and its current displayed submenu item `Flexible Endoscopes`? My current code that just prints a number to the screen:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');

    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects' );
    function wpse16243_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items )
    {
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( $menu_item->current ) {
        var_dump($GLOBALS['wpse16243_title'] = $menu_item->menu_item_parent);
        break;
    }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
    }
```